# Package listed in .manifest is not installed with OS

Tags: system-installation, preinstallation

After visiting [How do I list the default installed packages?](https://askubuntu.com/q/48886/256099), I read [ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-i386.manifest](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-i386.manifest)   and found (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) that it lists `gparted 0.18.0-1` but (we know that) gparted is **not** installed by default!

However, Gparted is installed when try Ubuntu (using Live CD Environment) hence seems to be removed while installing system.

So, I want to know Why package listed in `.manifest` is not installed with OS?

Comment: Related :http://askubuntu.com/questions/635974/is-this-package-shipped-by-default

Comment: It is uninstalled at the end of the installation. If you look at the messages, it will list GParted, a number of i18n/l10n packages and a few others.

Comment: `apt-cache show gparted` tells me : `Task: ubuntu-live, ubuntu-usb-live, edubuntu-live, edubuntu-usb-live, xubuntu-live, lubuntu-live, ubuntustudio-desktop, ubuntu-gnome-live` . So perhaps the installer checks that somehow ?

Comment: @muru btw, what is `i18n/l10n`?

Comment: [Internationalization and localization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization) - essentially getting software to support multiple natural languages. Once the user picks a language for installation, the installer removes the others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The manifest says what's on the CD. Some things are removed after the install but I haven't found a reliable way to work out what they are short of downloading the ISO.

if you have the ISO in front of you, compare `/casper/filesystem.manifest` and `/casper/filesystem-remove.manifest`.

It's that second file that contains packages that are on the CD that are removed after installation, unless they have other dependencies — which some of those things do.

Comment: I had not known about `/casper/filesystem-remove.manifest` +1